# Security Concerns on clientside (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, security

We are going to design and implement a UI for a big website. Owner of the site is really cautious about security issues. I wonder if there is a check list for client-side security recommendations, when designing and coding in Javascript.

Comment: Are the security concerns about server-side data security, or security regarding exploits for hacking the user's PC?

Comment: server-side data I think, but it is important that if the a user hacked us in a way like injection, we restrict his accessibility.
Finally, I mean all concerns which should be considered while working on Javascript

Comment: Well the obvious one is that if the user is able to enter data then you *must* implement server-side validation for that data. Optionally you can add client-side validation as well, which can provide a nicer user experience, but don't do only client-side.

Comment: But I wanne know if there is something to be done in javascript. any security concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/56/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3.pdf) as a start. It offers a suite of tests that you can systematically use to check your application for common vulnerabilities.

[Web application pen testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) is a buzz word for what you are trying to achieve. Scan the net for automated tools and background information.

Edit:

You mentioned that not only the client side is your concern, but the overall security of the entire application including the server. My advice would be that if you have never done security assessment of an application before, your boss/the owner of the site should probably consider hiring an external company/consultant for the job. They will do the job for less than it would probably cost if you and your team had to learn the details first. Plus, they have the advantage of having this done over and over again, so they are much less likely to overlook important details.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can easily be tricked. You need to build a system with server side has all the security and the client side will only acts as a interface similar to browser.

Encrypting using strong security certificate will also be an option you may consider.